# How to write a function that takes a dictionary and prints the entries of the dictionary in alphabetical order?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do this exercise:

> The order of key-value pairs in a dictionary is unpredictable but
> sometimes it makes sense to sort them by key. Write a function that
> takes a dictionary and prints the entries of the dictionary in
> alphabetical order. Use `sorted()` to sort the entries in the
> dictionary.
>
> For instance, given the input `{'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}`
>
> the program should print
>
> ```
> Age: 52
> City: Napier
> Name: Betty
> ```

This is the code I tried:

```
Entry = {'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}

for alphabet in Entry:
    Value = Entry['Name', 'City', 'Napier']

print(Value)
```

Do I have to sort key-value pairs by key first by using sorted?

So does it go like this?

I wonder if I am on the right track.

```
Entry = {'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}

for alphabet in Entry:
    Key_Name = sorted(Entry)
    Value = Entry['Name', 'City', 'Napier']

print(Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're on the right path. One solution would be:

```py
entries = {'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}

for key, value in sorted(entries.items()):
    print(f"{key.rjust(15)}: {value}")
```